# Inserting record in Hive by appending

Tags: hive, hdfs

I am executing INSERT statements on a Hive external table. I noticed that for each new INSERT, there is a new file created in the HDFS path referenced by the external table. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to have the new inserted data as append instead of creating new files?
2. Can I control it in such a way that up to certain size, say 1MB, only then Hive will create a new file to place the incoming inserts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudera says:

> The INSERT INTO syntax appends data to a table. The existing data files are left as-is, and the inserted data is put into one or more new data files.

Hive will append the table not the underlying files.

You can coerce hive to build tables using another create table, and forcing reducers to one.  This will copy the fragmented files in one table and combine them in another location in HDFS.  Then you could swap the files in HDFS.

You could place files in a holding area, then check the size of the files there in hdfs and move them over as above.  It seems easier however to temporarily hold the files on the local file system and move them over.

To combine files into a new file using hive you can try:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nostrict;
set hive.exec.compress.intermediate=false;
set hive.exec.compress.output=false;
set hive.exec.reducers.max=1;

create table if not exists db.table
stored as textfiel as
select * from db.othertable;
```

db.othertable is the table that has multiple fragemented files.  db.table will have a single text file containing the combined data.

I know this is not ideal and is more of a work around.